# Showing $\alpha(\beta+1)\leq\frac{5}{3}\alpha^2+\frac{1}{3}\beta^2$ for nonnegative integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

I found this lemma in a paper I was reading and it was not proved. There doesn't seem to be any obvious factorized form so how would one go about proving the inequality holds?

$$\alpha(\beta+1)\leq\frac{5}{3}\alpha^2+\frac{1}{3}\beta^2$$

$$\frac{5}{3}\alpha^2+\frac{1}{3}\beta^2-\alpha(\beta+1) \geq 0$$

$$5\alpha^2+\beta^2-3\alpha\beta-3\alpha \geq 0$$

Comment: But, for example, the first is not true $\alpha = 1/2,\beta = 1.$

Comment: @Phicar $\alpha, \beta$ are nonnegative integers.

Comment: @JetChung My bad, I did not see the title.

Comment: $$
\left(\beta-\frac 3 2 \alpha \right)^2 + \frac{11}4 \left( \alpha-\frac 6 {11} \right)^2 \ge \frac 9 {11} \text{ if $\alpha,\beta\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ ?}
$$

Answer (score 7):

Your required inequality can be adjusted as follows:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 & \le 5\alpha^2 + \beta^2 - 3\alpha\beta - 3\alpha \\
& = 4\alpha^2 - 4\alpha\beta + \beta^2 + \alpha^2 + \alpha\beta - 3\alpha \\
& = (2\alpha - \beta)^2 + \alpha(\alpha + \beta - 3)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Since $(2\alpha - \beta)^2 \ge 0$ and $\alpha \ge 0$, then \eqref{eq1A} can only *possibly not* be true if

$$\alpha + \beta - 3 \lt 0 \implies \alpha + \beta \lt 3 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

If $\alpha = 0$, then \eqref{eq1A} is always true. If $\alpha = 1$, then \eqref{eq2A} means either $\beta = 0$, which gives the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} to be $2$, or $\beta = 1$, which gives the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} to be $0$. Next, for $\alpha = 2$, \eqref{eq2A} shows only $\beta = 0$ is possible, with this giving the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} to be $2$. Finally, for $\alpha \ge 3$, \eqref{eq2A} shows there's no non-negative value for $\beta$ possible.

This confirms \eqref{eq1A} is always true for all non-negative integer values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative proof inspired by Michael Hardy:

$$5\alpha^2+\beta^2-3\alpha\beta-3\alpha \geqslant 0 \iff 20\alpha^2+4\beta^2-12\alpha 
\beta-12\alpha \geqslant 0$$

$$20\alpha^2+4\beta^2-12\alpha \beta-12\alpha 
= (2\beta-3\alpha )^2+11\alpha^2-12\alpha \\
=\begin{cases}
(2\beta-3\alpha )^2+\alpha (11\alpha-12)>0,  & \text{if $\alpha>1$} \\
(2\beta-3)^2-1 \geqslant 0, & \text{if $\alpha=1$} \\
4\beta^2 \geqslant 0 & \text{if $\alpha=0$}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
"=" \iff \alpha=1, 2\beta-3=\pm 1 \text{ or } \alpha=\beta=0\\ \iff (\alpha, \beta)\in \{(0,0), (1,1), (1,2)\}
$$

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks, edited.