# Upper bound for $a\cdot(b + 1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

My task is to prove

$$a\cdot (b + 1) \leq \frac{5}{3}a^2 + \frac{1}{3}b^2$$
$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{N}$

It is not directly obvious to me, what this is the case. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing $\alpha(\beta+1)\leq\frac{5}{3}\alpha^2+\frac{1}{3}\beta^2$ for nonnegative integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3909210/showing-alpha-beta1-leq-frac53-alpha2-frac13-beta2-for-nonnegat)

Comment: Rearrange & complete the square.